# How do I get a user's location using Koala in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have the following code in my sessions controller which saves information such as Facebook friends, likes, and a user profile to my DB. The profile includes the user's location and gender but it gets saved into the DB as a string so I can't extract it.

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(current_user.token)
current_user.profile = @graph.get_object("me")
current_user.likes = @graph.get_connections("me", "likes")
current_user.friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
current_user.save
```

Going into the console, I can get the profile of the last user via:

```
u = User.last.profile
```

But this doesn't let me call for the location specifically, like:

```
User.last.profile.location
```

User table looks like

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "provider"
t.string   "uid"
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "token"
t.string   "likes"
t.string   "profile"
t.string   "location"
t.string   "interests"
t.string   "birthday"
t.string   "activities"
t.string   "friends"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@oauth_token)
@user = graph.get_object("me")
location = @user["location"]["name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `koala v2.2` and my application Facebook API Version is `v2.4`.
I did not get `location` information using  just `get_object("me")` request. I had to pass `location` as `fields` parameter like

```
get_object("me?fields=first_name,last_name,location")
```

May be this information will be helpful for someone.

N.B: Of course you have to enable `user_location` scope.

Comment: Very helpful indeed thanks! It seems fb keeps changing it's API. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've used to work this out is using scopes and call these scopes in the view, which might not be the best way but is a quick fix.

The User model can be scoped by:

```
scope :CityName, where("profile like '%location: CityName%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

to use Facebook Checkins since yesterday e.g.:

```
unless graph.get_connections('me', 'checkins', :since => 'yesterday').blank?
checkin = graph.get_connections('me', "checkins", :since => 'yesterday')
lat = checkin[0]['place']['location']['latitude']
long = checkin[0]['place']['location']['longitude']
```

Comment: The question was for location in the user's profile, not their check-ins, but this could serve useful in future for anyone who might need it.